# VBA - How to hide pivot fields?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to remove a certain field in my pivot using this code below but it is not working. What's wrong with this code?

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim df As PivotField
Dim rows As Variant

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

'Remove rows not needed
rows = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")

For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
   pt.PivotFields(rows(0)).Orientation = xlHidden
   pt.PivotFields(rows(1)).Orientation = xlHidden
   pt.PivotFields(rows(2)).Orientation = xlHidden
   pt.PivotFields(rows(3)).Orientation = xlHidden
Next pt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments inside:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim df As PivotField
Dim PTrows As Variant '<< DO NOT USE ROWS WHICH IS RESERVED OBJECT INSTRUCTION

'Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1) << YOU DON'T NEED IT IF YOU HAVE A LOOP

'Remove rows not needed
PTrows = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")

For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
   pt.PivotFields(PTrows(0)).Orientation = xlHidden
   pt.PivotFields(PTrows(1)).Orientation = xlHidden
   pt.PivotFields(PTrows(2)).Orientation = xlHidden
   pt.PivotFields(PTrows(3)).Orientation = xlHidden
Next pt
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your help and advice Sir! I will take note on that :)